# Letter Frequency Table, Including Special Characters?

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters

Does anyone know of a table somewhere for relative frequencies of not just letters, but also punctuation/special characters?  I need to use the table to set the letter frequencies for my Huffman code key generation algorithm, but in over half an hour googling I have been unable to find anything that gives a comparison between letters and special characters (I have found letter tables, and I even found one comparing just special characters, but nothing to compare them with each other).

Comment: This any good? http://mtgap.bilfo.com/letter_frequency.html (top link of quite a few on https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=punctuation+frequency+analysis)

Comment: Not really.  I actually need their numerical frequencies, not just the sequence from most common to least common, because I also need to be able to compare the combined frequencies of two different characters with those of single characters, and even larger groups.  (Thats the way Huffman compression works.)

Comment: @cbuckley That might be useful... although unfortunately it doesn't give the punctuation frequencies compared to other characters.  Looks like I'll have to do without, and just use the target string to generate the key.